# Display 'Sorry, this item sold.' msg on sold/out of stock products

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, product-page

I have Magento set to show out of stock products but currently if someone accesses the product link directly, there is no message indicating that the product is out of stock. The Add To Cart button does not show, but I expected a message to show in it's place. How do I add this?

Answer (score 2):

In my `catalog.xml` i have found this, for simple product

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Simple)</label>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.availability" as="product_type_availability" template="catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml" />
        </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
```

The template that is responsible with "in stock" and "out of stock" messages is `catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml`

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.availability" as="product_type_availability" template="catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml" />
```

You will need to add it, as well for `PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable`, `PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped`, and `PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual`

Comment: Thanks. Your answer got me thinking, and it turns out I had disabled 'Display products availability in stock in the frontend' in Admin-System-Configuration-Inventory. Enabling this gives me in stock/out of stock messages which will work fine for now.

Comment: Nice :D ... Good luck !